# Nested function does not see local variable in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to use a matlab module named [optprop](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13788-optprop-a-color-properties-toolbox) in my octave environment. It seems that code has some compatibility issue. In particular, when I try to call

```
xyz_image = rgb2xyz(rgb_image)
```

I get following error:

```
error: 'cwf' undefined near line 1809 column 15
error: called from
    astm>getcwf at line 1809 column 4
    astm at line 1843 column 5
    makecwf>tryastm at line 74 column 5
    makecwf at line 59 column 9
    wpt at line 33 column 6
    i_xyz2xyz at line 28 column 6
    i_rgb2xyz at line 54 column 5
    optproc at line 315 column 7
    rgb2xyz at line 49 column 33
    rgb2xyz_norm2 at line 10 column 12
```

The code which causes error is in astm.m file. This file defines function:

```
function z=astm(op,varargin)
    persistent cwf lam
    %cwf initialization

    %nested function
    function z=getcwf(name, varargin)
        %...
        z=cwf;  %here cwf is undefined
        %...

    %actual nested function call
    z=getcwf(varargin{:});
    %...
```

From my point of view everything's fine here. Nested function should see cwf. Even though I use octave, it should support everything, since optprop package have been updated in 2007 last time. I also experimented with nested functions, and following code works just fine:

```
function nested_function_test()
    disp('inside outer function');
    local_variable = 'local string content';

    function nested_function()
        disp('inside nested function');
        disp(local_variable);
    end

    disp('after nested function declaration');
    nested_function();
end
```

I do not see any difference between those chunks of code. Why cwf is undefined?

UPDATE:

Just in case. Current workaround which works for me:

```
function z=getcwf(name, varargin)
    cwf = varargin{end - 1};
    lam = varargin{end};
    %...


varargin{end + 1} = cwf;
varargin{end + 1} = lam;
z=getcwf(varargin{:});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is at all relevant in your case, but octave in particular occasionally has trouble "seeing" changes until the session is restarted. E.g. see [this bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46282). I have also witnessed this behaviour with editing built-in functions and in other scenarios. Also, while octave supports nested functions, some functionality is still missing. It would be useful to mention if the problem persists when restarting your octave session, and whether or not it is also present in matlab (if you have access to it).

Comment: Thanks, Tasos, but it does not seem to be the case. Problem remains for several days, so session restart does not work. As for functionality support, I believe octave should already have full support for nested functions. I've attached working example, and I do not see any difference between the module which I'm trying to run and this MWE I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a definite bug in octave. In your MWE, if you make `local_variable` persistent, then the buggy behaviour will be reproduced. i.e.

```
function nested_function_test()
  disp('inside outer function');
  persistent local_variable;  % <-- change here, make local_variable persistent
  local_variable = 'local string content';

  function nested_function()
    disp('inside nested function');
    disp(local_variable);  % <-- local_variable no longer visible
  end

  disp('after nested function declaration');
  nested_function();
end
```

The above will work in matlab, and fail in octave.

In particular, in matlab, during a debug session inside the nested function, if you type `whos` you will see two stacks of variables, one (empty) workspace local to the nested function, and another corresponding to the outer function, to which the nested inner function has access to, containing the persistent variable.

In octave, typing `whos` inside the nested function simply returns an empty local workspace and nothing else. (and if you remove the `persistent` line, you will see that octave simply seems to 'import' the outer local variables into the local workspace, rather than have access to both inner and outer, so it seems that octave has a different approach to how it creates nested functions).

<s>I would encourage you to file this as a formal bug in the [octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave)</s><sup>1</sup>. It appears that perhaps the devs treat persistent variables as a special case and forgot to account for this behaviour in their particular implementation of nested functions. Presumably the 'import' step looks at variables in a particular place, and the persistent variable is stored elsewhere and missed?

---

<sub>1: Ah, it appears this bug has already been reported and confirmed, but not yet fixed: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?42126</sub>

Comment: (update: bug has reportedly been fixed on development branch; see bug tracker. I have not confirmed this)